# Meteor - explanation of how templates are made available from packages that you include?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to figure out how Meteor works.  I read the following in the book Discover Meteor, in their section on adding user accounts:

> We could just use Meteor's built-in UI for accounts (with mrt add
>   accounts-ui) but since we've built our whole app with Bootstrap, we'll
>   use the accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown package instead (don't worry,
>   the only difference is the styling). On the command line, we type:

```
$ mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
$ mrt add accounts-password
```

> Those two commands make the special accounts templates available to
>   us; we can include them in our site using the `{{loginButtons}}` helper.

Thre are a couple of things I don't understand.  First, I thought templates in meteor had to be in
`*.html` files and be enclosed in the  tag.  Second, I thought that the syntax for including a template in a handlebars file was `{{> loginButtons}}` not `{{loginButtons}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{loginButtons}}` returned complete HTML. This is about to change in a soon to be released version of Meteor. Meteor's Template engine is changing and returning raw HTML in't possible anymore (it can be generated as an object though).

In the new version `{{loginButtons}}` is now `{{>loginButtons}}`

The reason `{{loginButtons}}` works is there is a HTML Helper to `loginButtons` that returns raw html as a string which is then placed there. The problem with this is it's not a very good idea if you want stuff in there to be reactive (its better to have proper DOM).

The templates from `accounts-ui` are in html files. They are added in the packages. You can take a peek at them here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled